# "leave" command and auto-disconnect after X minutes of inactivity

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a music bot and have ran into two problems.

Firstly, how would I go about implementing a `/leave` command? When a user who is in the channel decides they no longer want/need the bot in their channel, they simply type `/leave` and the bot disconnects and wipes the queue?

Secondly, how would I implement a timer which would disconnect the bot after X minutes of inactivity? For example, if the bot reaches the end of the queue and no further songs have been added and no commands executed, say after 15 minutes, the bot would automatically disconnect from the channel and wipe the queue?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

### Making the bot disconnect from the voice channel

Not knowing how you structured your commands it's hard to give you the exact code. All I can tell you is that I would look to see whether the bot is the user's voice channel and, if so, leave it using the [`VoiceConnection.disconnect()`](http://v) method. It would look like this:

```js
// Assuming 'message' is the message with the command
let { channelID } = message.member.voice // Get the user's voice channel ID
if (channelID) {
  // Find an existing connection to that channel
  let connection = client.voice.connections.find(conn => conn.channel.id == channelID)
  if (connection) // If you find one, use .disconnect()
    connection.disconnect()
}
```

---

### Creating an inactivity timer

Again, I can't give you the exact code since I don't know how you set up your music bot. This is the gist of it: when the queue ends you can create a timer using [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), if the bot is used before the timeout ends, you can cancel it with [`clearTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp).
Here's how I would do it:

```js
// Somewhere so that it's in an accessible scope
let timeoutID;

// After the queue has ended
timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
  // This will run if the timeout reaches its end
  // You can adapt the code above to disconnect from the voice channel
}, 15 * 60 * 1000) // You should use the time in ms

// If the bot is used again
clearTimeout(timeoutID)
timeoutID = undefined
```